# Как создать словарь из списка списков? (из списка пар: ключ, значение. Результат: каждому ключу—список значений)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, словари

```
dict_numbers = {}
list_numbers = [['1', '1'],['1', '2'],['2', '3']]
for i in list_numbers:
    for j in i:
        if j[0] in dict_numbers.keys():
            dict_numbers[j[0]].append(j[1])
        else:
            dict_numbers[j[0]] = []
            dict_numbers[j[0]].append(j[1])
```

Не понимаю в чем ошибка. Нужно чтобы создался словарь, а значение ключа должно быть списком.

Результат:

```
{'1' : ['1', '2'], '2': ['3']}
```

Comment: второй цикл лишний

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list_numbers = [['1', '1'],['1', '2'],['2', '3']]
for i in list_numbers:  # i == ['1', '1'] 
    for j in i:  # j == '1'
        if j[0]   # j[0] == '1'[0] ???
```

Comment: `j[0] == '1'` это очевидно, ошибку вызывает `j[1]`

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы создать словарь из списка пар ключ/значение, поместив значения в списки:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in list_numbers:
    d[key].append(value)
```

[`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdic) уже ведёт себя как словарь, но можно точный тип получить: `dict(d)`.

#### Результат

```
{'1': ['1', '2'], '2': ['3']}
```

Можно без `defaultdict`:

```
d = {key: [] for key, _ in list_numbers}
for key, value in list_numbers:
    d[key].append(value)
```

Результат тот же.

Answer (score 0):

```
dict_numbers = {}
list_numbers = [['1', '1'],['1', '2'],['2', '3']]
for i in list_numbers:
    dict_numbers[i[0]] = i[1]

print(dict_numbers)

# {'2': '3', '1': '2'}
```

будет создан словарь только с 2-мя элементами, т.к. в списке два листа с одинаковыми первыми элементами

Answer (score 0):

Списками нельзя индексировать словари по сколько этот тип данных является ИЗМЕНЯЕМЫМ. Словарь - хеш массив. И если индексировать списками словари, то при изменении списка изменится и его хеш, и элемент больше будет нельзя извлечь из словаря