# Как красиво преобразовать один список в другой? Дан пример вида этих списков

Tags: list, python-3.5

Здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста, как в Python 3.5 при помощи минимального количества строчек кода (м.б. какие-нибудь zip, dict или ещё что-то) преобразовать массив 'a' в 'b'? Понятно, что можно циклами и проверками в них, но может быть есть какая-то красивая конструкция?
Вот пример входного и выходного массива:

```
a = [['a', 0, 0],['a', 0, 1],['a', 0, 2],['a', 0, 3],
     ['a', 1, 0],['a', 1, 1],['a', 1, 3],
     ['a', 2, 0],['a', 2, 3],
     ['b', 0, 1],['b', 0, 3],
     ['b', 1, 0],['b', 1, 1],['b', 1, 2],['b', 1, 3],
     ['b', 2, 0],['b', 2, 2],['b', 2, 3]]

b = [['a',0,[0,1,2,3]],
     ['a',1,[0,1,3]],
     ['a',2,[0,3]],
     ['b',0,[1,3]],
     ['b',1,[0,1,2,3]],
     ['b',2,[0,2,3]]]
```

Comment: Исправил ошибку в массиве b. До этого забыл добавить скобки. Сейчас всё правильно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = [['a', 0, 0],['a', 0, 1],['a', 0, 2],['a', 0, 3],
     ['a', 1, 0],['a', 1, 1],['a', 1, 3],
     ['a', 2, 0],['a', 2, 3],
     ['b', 0, 1],['b', 0, 3],
     ['b', 1, 0],['b', 1, 1],['b', 1, 2],['b', 1, 3],
     ['b', 2, 0],['b', 2, 2],['b', 2, 3]]

b = []
for j in sorted(set([tuple(i[:2]) for i in a])):
    b.append([j[0], j[1], [i[-1] for i in a if tuple(i[:2]) == j]])
```

Comment: Круто :) Спасибо, буду разбираться. Принимаю, как решение.

Answer (score 0):

Похоже сам решил :) помог местный пост от пользователя @jfs [Как создать словарь из списка списков? (из списка пар: ключ, значение. Результат: каждому ключу—список значений)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/601945/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82?rq=1)

Получилось так:

```
        from collections import defaultdict

        a = [['a', 0, 0],['a', 0, 1],['a', 0, 2],['a', 0, 3],
             ['a', 1, 0],['a', 1, 1],['a', 1, 3],
             ['a', 2, 0],['a', 2, 3],
             ['b', 0, 1],['b', 0, 3],
             ['b', 1, 0],['b', 1, 1],['b', 1, 2],['b', 1, 3],
             ['b', 2, 0],['b', 2, 2],['b', 2, 3]]

        b = defaultdict(list)

        for key1, key2, value in a:
            b[key1, key2].append(value)

        for key in b:
            print(key[0], key[1], b[key])
        # Получается то, что я хотел :)
```

Хотя, если можно лучше, то будет интересно узнать как. Заранее спасибо.